# Compute a convolution with weights that where computed by another function

Tags: pytorch

I would like to perform a conv2d but a special one because I compute the weights of a conv2d layer in a function for each sample. Can I simply assign the weights of a given layer for each sample?

I am implementing the Spatially variant convolution of this paper : https://arxiv.org/abs/1804.00389

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

It is actually very simple : torch.nn.functional.conv2d !